# PHP regular expression help

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on fixing a few bugs / adding features to a site somebody else built.  Can anyone tell me what the following regexes do?  I'm semi familiar with regular expressions, but I haven't the foggiest idea what these are trying to accomplish.

`````
$qsReplace = preg_replace('/\\\t/', "\t", $qsReplace);
$qsReplace = preg_replace('/\\\/', '\\\\\\', $qsReplace);
$qsReplace = preg_replace('/\$([0-9])/','\$````~~~~$1', $qsReplace);
$queryString = preg_replace('/\$\`\`\`\`\~\~\~\~([0-9])/','\$$1', $queryString);
`````

I suspect that whoever coded this was a little bit strange, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What happened to `mysql_real_escape_string`, `str_replace`, `(int)` ?

Comment: They actually are running `mysql_real_escape_string` on the query string before this block executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converts `\t` into and actual tab

- `$qsReplace = preg_replace('/\\\t/', "\t", $qsReplace);`

Escapes Double backslashes, Can be replaced with `addslhases();`

- `$qsReplace = preg_replace('/\\\/', '\\\\\\', $qsReplace);`

Finds a `$` followed by a digit such as `$01` and replaces with `backtick` x4 + `~` x4 (pre)

- ````` $qsReplace = preg_replace('/\$([0-9])/','\$````~~~~$1', $qsReplace); `````

Removes the `$`,`backtick`,`~`

- `` $queryString = preg_replace('/\$\`\`\`\`\~\~\~\~([0-9])/','\$$1', $queryString); ``

Obviously the last programmer did not understand a few things.

Answer (score 2):

The third one finds a dollar sign followed by a digit and inserts four backticks and four tildes between the number and the dollar sign. The fourth one removes these backticks and tildes between a dollar and the number.

I would suspect some more data juggling going on between the two and a hope that no input ever would contain four backticks followed by four tildes...

Comment: Sigh... these are actually run more or less back to back.  I'm starting to think that the guy who coded this site intentionally made it bloated and obfuscated so nobody else would be able to maintain it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace an escaped \t with a
   tab (\t)
2. Escapes double
   backslashes
3. Finds a dollar sign followed by a digit and inserts four backticks and four tildes between the number and the dollar sign.
4. Removes these backticks and tildes between a dollar and the number.

(3 & 4 thanks to chx)